# Некликабельные кнопки в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Появилась проблема с кнопками.

Всё работает отлично до некоторого момента:

1. После смерти игрока появляется меню, где ему нужно выбрать что он будет
   делать дальше (всего две кнопки).
2. Почти всегда все работает отлично , но иногда кнопки просто не срабатывают(становятся некликабельными) и для продолжения игры нужно перезайти в нее.

Меню я делаю активным и неактивным строкой:

```
GameObjct.SetActive(true)/(false);
```

Иерархия (во время бага) :
X1 и X2 - кнопки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: меню world space или overlay?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q overlay

Comment: проблема в эдиторе повторяется?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Насколько я понял вопрос в том повторяется ли проблема.Это происходит где-то 1 раз из 8

Comment: я имел в виду это проявляется в собранной версии игры или в редакторе тоже?

Comment: @Veudd можете прикрепить скриншот меню из окна Hierarchy?

Comment: Возможно что-то блокирует рейкаст клика по кнопкам, такое было в моей игре, изображение с 0 альфой мешало. Иерархию объектов *во время бага* надо посмотреть.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q И в редакторе , и в собранной игре.

Comment: @Alt F4 прикрепил

Comment: EventSystem отсутствует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень глупая ошибка ,но сравнив два окна иерархии я обнаружил ,что баг происходит из-за того ,что нету EventSystem(В некоторых уровнях) и после смерти мы просто не можем "считывать" нажатия .